# Linq date comparision

Tags: c#, linq

My query is like

```
var TMJM = (from TT in r2ge.Transcription_Tracker
            join TMA in r2ge.Transcription_Master on TT.Transcription_Id equals TMA.Transcription_Id
            select new
            {
                Trans_Id = TMA.Transcription_Id,
                Modified_dtm = TMA.Modified_dtm
            }).Distinct();

var qq = TMJM.Where(dr => (dr.Modified_dtm.Date >= sev_back_datetime) && (dr.Modified_dtm.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date));
```

It gives output `Enumeration yielded no results` while Data is there
But when I separate start date and end date then It will show date but when I combine both start and end date then It won't give output..
Any mistake in query?

Comment: Have a think about what happens at the edge cases when sev_back_datetime is 31st December or today_date_datetime is 1st January, and that will give you a pointer as to the problem with this algorithm.

Comment: thats right..I have traced it then I got what is wrong in previous query @Peregrine

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating each part of the date could be fraught with issue. I am assuming you are doing this to remove the time portion which can sometimes be problematic. Subsequently you can just evaluate the 'date' portion of the date time variable. This little example should explain.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

        dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-50));
        dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-51));
        dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-52));
        dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-53));
        dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-99));
        dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100));
        dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-101));

        var sev_back_datetime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100);

        Console.WriteLine(sev_back_datetime.Date.ToShortDateString());
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------");

        var query = from date in dates 
                    where date.Date >= sev_back_datetime.Date && 
                          date.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date 
                    select date;

        foreach (var date in query.ToList())
            Console.WriteLine(date.ToShortDateString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```

**EDIT - a direct example for you.**

```
        var TMJM = (from TT in r2ge.Transcription_Tracker
                    join TMA in r2ge.Transcription_Master on TT.Transcription_Id equals TMA.Transcription_Id
                    select new
                    {
                        Trans_Id = TMA.Transcription_Id,
                        Modified_dtm = TMA.Modified_dtm
                    }).Distinct();


        var qq = TMJM.Where(dr => (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(dr.Modified_dtm) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(sev_back_datetime)) && (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(dr.Modified_dtm) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now)));
```

Comment: You can use [DateTime.Today](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  instead of `DateTime.Now.Date` to get the current date

Comment: I got an err of `The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.` see my update plz

Comment: @user4864757 ok no problem, rather than using the `dr.Modified_dtm.Date` can you instead use the `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(dr.Modified_dtm)` this function effectivly removes the time portion of the date variable.Thus achieving the same result. I have updated my answer to include an example for you.